# Visual Studio Nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

Am trying to get nuget packages into my visual studio project.

NuGet Package manager is not package source of 'nuget.org'... just show Ms VS offline packages.  Is there any setting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

got this working,  just need to add:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

[image]

Nuget in the Package Souces.